# How to open a view on long pressing on a collection view's particular row in swift?

Tags: swift, collectionview

This is the code I am using:

In viewDidLoad-

```
 let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapLeaveView))
        self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
```

The method-

```
@objc func tapLeaveView(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
            if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
                let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
                if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: touchPoint) {
                    
                // code for the view I want
                
                }
            }
    }
```

It works but it opens view on every row and I want it to open it at row no- 2 only.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code, you are getting the wrong touchpoint, it gets the wrong indexPath.

To get correct touchPoint

```
let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: collectionView)
```

Also, first, you need to find all the indexes of the particular row and need to check whether it contains in a row or not. If contain then you need to perform your action.

```
// Calculation for finding row index for particuler row
let numberOfColumn = 5 // Number of column in collection
let rowForTap = 2 // Your particuler row
let startingIndex = ((rowForTap * numberOfColumn) - numberOfColumn)
let arrGestureIndex: [Int] = Array((startingIndex)..<startingIndex + numberOfColumn) // Indexes of particuler row
```

In last

```
@objc func tapLeaveView(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: collectionView)
        if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: touchPoint), arrGestureIndex.contains(indexPath.item) {
            print(indexPath)
            // code for the view you want
            
        }
    }
}
```

Another way you can add Gesture for particular cell inside the cellForItem method.